# Does Uploadify save the image or the Controller action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, uploadify

When using Uploadify, you specify a folder for the image (eg 'folder' : '/uploads'), however in the controller action of an MVC app the image is also being saved!

Im confused - is it Uplodify or the controller action that saves the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LillyPop - Uploadify sends the filestream via ajax to the controller action, so it's the controller action (or service class called by the action) that does the heavy lifting. you'll typically see something like this in your javascript method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initupLoadify() {
        $("#fileInput").uploadify({
            uploader: '<%=Url.Content("~/scripts/swf/uploadify.swf")%>',
            script: '<%=Url.Content("~/en/PropertyDocument/Upload/")%>',
            cancelImg: '<%=Url.Content("~/Content/cancel.png") %>',
            auto: true,
            sizeLimit: 5500000,
            fileDataName: 'fileData',
            scriptData: { 'propertyId': $("#PropertyID").val() },
            buttonText: 'Add Document',
            onComplete: function(event, queueID, fileObj, response) {
                $("#msg").html(response);
                return true;
            },
            onCancel: function(evt, queueID, fileObj, data) {
                $("#msg").html("<br />Operation cancelled");
                return true;
            },
            onOpen: function(evt, queueID, fileObj) {
                $("#msg").html("<br />Upload in progress");
                return true;
            },
            onError: function(event, queueID, fileObj, errorObj) {
                $("#msg").html(fileObj.name + " was not uploaded ");
                if (errorObj.status == 404)
                    $("#msg").html("Could not find upload script. Use a path relative to: " + "<?= getcwd() ?>");
                else if (errorObj.type === "HTTP")
                    $("#msg").html("error " + errorObj.type + ": " + errorObj.status);
                else if (errorObj.type === "File Size")
                    $("#msg").html(fileObj.name + " " + errorObj.type + " Limit: " + errorObj.info / 1000 + " KB");
                else
                    $("#msg").html("error " + errorObj.type + ": " + errorObj.text);
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

the section `script: '<%=Url.Content("~/en/PropertyDocument/Upload/")%>'` is where the controller action is defined.

Comment: Jim, So why do we need to specify a uploadify folder for the file? And if I stop my controller saving the image Uplodify saves it in this said folder. Are there two ways to save a file?

Comment: lillypop - afaik, the swf file CAN save the file if you provide the 'folder' default. by not providing that, my understanding is that you are then just doing a straight httpost to the controller. this is how i've always approached this, so my understanding may be flawed or outmoded in later revisions

Comment: Jim I was wrong in my first comment, if my controller doesn't save the file then uploadify doesn't save it, Its only my controller that will save the file (I tried both ways), im not even sure why there is a 'folder' property its led me astray (unless uploadify can be asked to save - which I cant find in the docs). Im not going to use the folder property, as its working fine without it. - Many thanks for your help

Comment: LillyPop - no probs, glad you've walked over it and put it to bed!